# Manage AWS EKS cluster using online platform like killerkonda

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

What are all steps to connect to AWS EKS cluster using online platform like killerkonda, etc..
So that I can manage my AWS EKS cluster using these online tool.

I tried connecting to https://killercoda.com/ online tool and selected kubernetes.
My end goal is to perform all production level operation on my cluster without installing any tool locally

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS CLI on linux

```html
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Configure your profile with the aws configure sso wizard

```html
$ aws configure sso
SSO session name (Recommended): my-sso
SSO start URL [None]: https://my-sso-portal.awsapps.com/start
SSO region [None]: us-east-1
SSO registration scopes [None]: sso:account:access
```

Cross check AWS CLI is working

```html
aws s3 ls --profile <AWS SSO profile>
```

Install kubectl

```html
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" 
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
chmod +x kubectl
sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/   OR mv ./kubectl ~/.local/bin/kubectl
kubectl version --client
```

Configures kubectl so that you can connect to an Amazon EKS cluster.
EKS uses the Kubernetes kubectl command-line tool for cluster management. You need to configure kubectl to authenticate and communicate with the EKS cluster.

```html
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster-name> --profile <AWS SSO profile>
```

Verify the cluster configuration:

```html
kubectl get svc
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods
```

Comment: Supported reference links:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html